# Why array outside code is empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

```
if (args[0] === "help") {
    var help_array = [];
    fs.readdir('./commands/', (err, files) => {
        files.forEach((response) => {
            var commandFile = require('./commands/' + response);
            help_array.push(commandFile.getHelp());
            console.log(help_array); // <----- array with elements
        });
    });
    console.log(help_array); // <----------- empty array []
    return;
}
```

Why is this happening? How i can solve this? It is related to async function?

Comment: The `.readdir()` function is **asynchronous**.

Comment: you can use `fs.readDirSync` for more reference https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options
and to have better understanding about synchronous and asynchronous
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript